# Globbing/pathname expansion with colon as separator

Tags: bash, shell, path, glob, expansion

How can I convert a string containing glob characters such as

```
/var/lib/gems/*/bin
```

into a colon-separated string of filenames (i.e. PATH compatible) matching the pattern?

i.e. `echo /var/lib/gems/*/bin` will return

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin
```

I want

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin
```

instead.

The obvious approach is simply to replace the space character with ':' via `tr`, but that doesn't work if the filename itself contains the space character.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, I thought of a better solution: use a shell function.

```
function join() {
    local IFS=$1
    shift
    echo "$*"
}

mystring=$(join ':' /var/lib/gems/*/bin)
```

Answer (score 13):

This should do it for you:

```
dirs=(/var/lib/gems/*/bin)    # put filenames (dirnames) in an array
saveIFS=$IFS IFS=':'          # set the Internal Field Separator to the desired delimiter
dirs=("${dirs[*]}")           # convert the array to a scalar with the new delimiter
IFS=$saveIFS                  # restore IFS
```

Answer (score 6):

```
PATH="$(printf "%s:" /usr/*/bin)"
PATH="${PATH%:}"
```

Comment: This works, but I'd use a different variable. You can also do the inital assignment this way: `printf -v varname "%s:" /var/lib/gems/*/bin`

Comment: Almost perfect. I think I like piping to sed to remove the trailing colon though ala http://stackoverflow.com/a/5074995/69002

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That's a beautiful oneliner. IMHO it should be the top answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty trivial if you drop into Perl:

```
perl -e 'print join ":", @ARGV' /var/lib/gems/*/bin
```

Or Python:

```
python -c 'import sys; print ":".join(sys.argv[1:])' /var/lib/gems/*/bin
```

Or any number of other popular scripting languages.

Comment: It seems as though this might be the best approach overall (the IFS fiddling is a bit messy), although it is a shame to have have to use an external program...

Comment: definitely the way to go if you want a one-liner

Answer (score 4):

No need to mess with `IFS`, zsh can join arrays with a simple variable flag:

```
dirs=(/var/lib/gems/*/bin(N))
dirs=${(j.:.)dirs}
```

The `(N)` on the first line suppresses a warning if there are no files; the `(j.:.)` joins the array with `:`s. Works with 0, 1, or multiple matches.

Comment: @Michaël not that I've found, though ZSH does often still surprise me so I can't say for sure that it can't.

Answer (score 3):

without saving IFS and command substitution

```
dirs=(/var/lib/gems/*/bin) ; IFS=: eval 'dirs="${dirs[*]}"'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
printf "%s\n" /var/lib/gems/*/bin | tr "\n" ":"
```

Comment: Close! But if there's only one match, you get a colon at the end: "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:".  (And if there's no match, a single colon.)

Answer (score 1):

Another oneliner: `printf "%s\n" /var/lib/gems/*/bin | paste -s -d':'`

But @timo's answer is better in my opinion.