# How to remove the last character from a bash grep output

Tags: bash, grep

```
COMPANY_NAME=`cat file.txt | grep "company_name" | cut -d '=' -f 2`
```

outputs something like this

```
"Abc Inc";
```

What I want to do is I want to remove the trailing ";" as well. How can i do that? I am a beginner to bash. Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Same here. `cat`/`grep` = `grep`.

Comment: For the problem at hand, it could have been solve with just grep: COMPANY_NAME=$(grep -Po '(?<=company_name=)"[^"]*"' file.txt)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'd use `sed 's/;$//'`. eg:

```
COMPANY_NAME=`cat file.txt | grep "company_name" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | sed 's/;$//'`
```

Comment: Don't abuse `cat`s. `grep` can actually read files, did you know? ;-)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes, I know there are at least two ways to avoid `cat` here. I left in the cat in order to avoid changing the command line from the question beyond what was actually necessary to make it work.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Not really in all cases, simply grep without cat -v will hide invisible (e.g. malicious) characters, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202198/bash-why-does-x0d-x20-erase-the-line

Answer (score 81):

This will remove the last character contained in your COMPANY_NAME var regardless if it is or not a semicolon:

```
echo "$COMPANY_NAME" | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

Answer (score 61):

```
foo="hello world"
echo ${foo%?}
hello worl
```

Comment: THIS is the bash way, not the other piped contraptions.

Comment: I like it. Add extra ? for more characters to be removed.

Comment: This just made my day because I was trying to make a quick and dirty list of websites we had TLS keys for.
`for L in \`ls *key\` ; do echo ${L%.key} ; done`

Answer (score 35):

I'd use `head --bytes -1`, or `head -c-1` for short.

```
COMPANY_NAME=`cat file.txt | grep "company_name" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | head --bytes -1`
```

`head` outputs only the beginning of a stream or file. Typically it counts lines, but it can be made to count characters/bytes instead. `head --bytes 10` will output the first ten characters, but `head --bytes -10` will output everything except the last ten.

NB: you may have issues if the final character is multi-byte, but a semi-colon isn't

I'd recommend this solution over `sed` or `cut` because

- It's exactly what `head` was designed to do, thus less command-line options and an easier-to-read command
- It saves you having to think about regular expressions, which are cool/powerful but often overkill
- It saves your machine having to think about regular expressions, so will be imperceptibly faster

Comment: I've tested the other suggested solution and this seems as the best one (and a simple one!) for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: on OSX `brew install coreutils` then you can use `ghead -c-1`

Comment: Note that you'll probably have to chop off an extra byte (newline) if your output is from a program.

Answer (score 15):

I believe the cleanest way to strip a single character from a string with bash is:

```
echo ${COMPANY_NAME:: -1}
```

but I haven't been able to embed the grep piece within the curly braces, so your particular task becomes a two-liner:

```
COMPANY_NAME=$(grep "company_name" file.txt); COMPANY_NAME=${COMPANY_NAME:: -1}
```

This will strip any character, semicolon or not, but can get rid of the semicolon specifically, too.
To remove ALL semicolons, wherever they may fall:

```
echo ${COMPANY_NAME/;/}
```

To remove only a semicolon at the end:

```
echo ${COMPANY_NAME%;}
```

Or, to remove multiple semicolons from the end:

```
echo ${COMPANY_NAME%%;}
```

For great detail and more on this approach, The Linux Documentation Project covers a lot of ground at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: the first one didn't work for me, but `echo ${var:0:-1}` did

Answer (score 8):

Using `sed`, if you don't know what the last character actually is:

```
$ grep company_name file.txt | cut -d '=' -f2 | sed 's/.$//'
"Abc Inc"
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `\{1\}` since `.` means a single character.

Answer (score 5):

Don't abuse `cat`s. Did you know that `grep` can read files, too?

The canonical approach would be this:

```
grep "company_name" file.txt | cut -d '=' -f 2 | sed -e 's/;$//'
```

the smarter approach would use a single `perl` or `awk` statement, which can do filter and different transformations at once. For example something like this:

```
COMPANY_NAME=$( perl -ne '/company_name=(.*);/ && print $1' file.txt )
```

Answer (score 3):

don't have to chain so many tools. Just one awk command does the job

```
 COMPANY_NAME=$(awk -F"=" '/company_name/{gsub(/;$/,"",$2) ;print $2}' file.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can strip the beginnings and ends of a string by N characters using this bash construct, as someone said already

```
$ fred=abcdefg.rpm
$ echo ${fred:1:-4}
bcdefg
```

HOWEVER, this is not supported in older versions of bash.. as I discovered just now writing a script for a Red hat EL6 install process. This is the sole reason for posting here.
A hacky way to achieve this is to use sed with extended regex like this:

```
$ fred=abcdefg.rpm
$ echo $fred | sed -re 's/^.(.*)....$/\1/g'
bcdefg
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash using only one external utility:

```
IFS='= ' read -r discard COMPANY_NAME <<< $(grep "company_name" file.txt)
COMPANY_NAME=${COMPANY_NAME/%?}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the quotation marks are actually part of the output, couldn't you just use the -o switch to return everything between the quote marks?

```
COMPANY_NAME="\"ABC Inc\";" | echo $COMPANY_NAME | grep -o "\"*.*\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Some refinements to answer above. To remove more than one char you add multiple question marks. For example, to remove last two chars from variable $SRC_IP_MSG, you can use:

```
SRC_IP_MSG=${SRC_IP_MSG%??}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | grep "company_name" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d ';' -f 1
```

Comment: that was obvious!.sorry I overlooked that obvious thing.

Comment: as linus torvalds says, one of the most difficult things to find in a programmer is "good taste", which is difficult to define. but since you would benefit from it i will do so in this case: because of the initial `cat` every element of the pipeline that does real work operates on its standard input and its standard output. the benefit is that you can replace the `cat` with some other pipeline that produces output similar to `file.txt` and you don't have to change even a single character in the functional part of the pipeline. this allows drop-in pipeline reusability.

Comment: @Det fyb above (forgot to tag you, just like somebody might forget to remove the input argument when composing pipelines and wonder why the output isn't as expected)

Comment: @randomstring, while I don't really see this as you giving me a ["piece of your mind"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619430/1821548) (I lol'd by the way) it's rather extreme reusability to preserve the use of `cat` just to give you the possibility of changing it to something else later on. The only thing I could see it worth for is simplicity. If a user types `grep pattern file`, then I'm pretty damn sure he understands it's that first part which reads the file and where he starts piping it.

Comment: @Det thanks for taking it positively. it is reasonable to say `grep foo file | grep bar | wc` and it is reasonable to say `cat file | grep foo | grep bar | wc`. what is not reasonable is to give out useless cat awards for the second. there are several specific points to preseve them in my thesis on the subject. perhaps you might not appreciate them now as i didn't when i was not as experienced. i got pissed off not at you but at the people who should know better than to initiate and support the practice. hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Det my answer's now the accepted one; of course that's only one person's opinion other than me. thanks for the motivation to write it out.

Comment: @randomstring well, it's much better than the one OP originally accepted. The discussion there is also very useful and clarifies the point I was trying to make quite nicely. I upped your answer too. Also, it's not like _I_ was the one who had the motivation to go write an answer we can all be proud of. So all in all: glad you got pissed off. Even if not at me.

Comment: @Det why thank you! :-) looks like you are learning unix stuff with an eye on thoroughness. that's the right approach so wish you good luck! ps: i should offer my apologies in advance in case i am wrong and you are a unix veteran just looking to fill a couple of gaps in knowledge. LOL!

Comment: @randomstring far from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not finding that `sed 's/;$//'` works. It doesn't trim anything, though I'm wondering whether it's because the character I'm trying to trim off happens to be a "$". What does work for me is `sed 's/.\{1\}$//'`.