# In bash, how is the %? interpreted in this line?

Tags: bash

This was taken from  another [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074893/how-to-remove-the-last-character-from-a-bash-grep-output) that helped me out with something but there wasn't an explanation for the code and I'm not sure hwo to read it.
The problem was stripping trailing characters from a string in bash. This was one of the solutions.

```
foo="hello world"
echo ${foo%?}
hello worl
```

I'm confused why this works and how bash interprets the middle line.
I believe the ${ SOMETHING } is an evaluation, but its the "%?" that is confusing me.

Comment: This is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). We already have many Q&A entries in the knowledgebase explaining it. [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), [BashFAQ #73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) and [the relevant BashGuide entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) are also pertinent.

Comment: BTW, `echo "${foo%?}"` is more reliable -- leaving an expansion unquoted tells the shell to do a bunch of extra, potentially-unwanted processing steps on its output. And `printf '%s\n' "${foo%?}"` is even more reliable than that -- see the caveats in the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the POSIX spec for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: In that usage:
% -> delete next
? -> char

see: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#common_use

Comment: @LORDTEK, yes, that's the first link in the initial comment. :)

Comment: If you want, I will remove my comment. But even the same page, I linked on the related title. (title: common_use)

Comment: Sorry I clearly didn't search the right terms. Knowing what it is called is helpful. Should I delete the question since its a duplicate?

Comment: @MichaelAnonymous Leaving it up is fine, it now serves as a sign post for other people looking for the same.